# Can I use if else statement in Excel macro to decide which macro to run based on a cell value?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

If Cell "DB2" equals "Hot" then run Hot_Macro
If Cell "DB2" equals "Cold" then run Cold_Macro
If Cell "DB2" equals "Warm" then run Warm_Macro
If Cell "DB2" is blank end

Answer (score 4):

You call use a Call statement to run one macro from another. A minimalist example:

```
   Sub main_macro()
       If Range("A1").Value = "hot" Then
           Call hot_macro
       ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "cold" Then
           Call cold_macro
       Else
           Return
       End If
   End Sub

   Sub hot_macro()
       Range("A2").Value = "It's hot!"
   End Sub

   Sub cold_macro()
       Range("A2").Value = "It's cold!"
   End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. The Auto_Open is another user-created macro and has no special status other than firing when a workbook is opened.

Comment: this is amazing, @chuff